# Java/Groovy on-thread-exit action

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, groovy

I've been looking around SO for a while checking some implementations of Pools, Executors and Futures but none of them fit my purpose... or at least I can't implement it properly.

I have a lib of classes, all similar to:

```
class X implements Runnable {
   @Override 
   public void run() { 
    // do sth
   }
}
```

and I can't modify them.

And my class:

```
class Controller {
   private int threadState;

   void threadStart() {
     // run a thread (made from any of the classes above)
     // and when it exits change the threadState value to V
   }
}
```

All I need is to run a thread in threadStart(), which will do some action after exiting, but the threadStart() function should pass immediately.

Do you have any good ideas to solve this in Java or/and Groovy? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible (but somewhat ugly) way to accomplish this would be to wrap your task around another runnable, before executing it. The wrapper would be responsible for delegating to the actual task, and invoking the call back method when done:

```
void changeThreadState() {
    // This is your call back, in controller
}

void threadStart() {
    final X task = new X(); // task creation (variable has to be final)

    final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            task.run();
            changeThreadState();
        }
    });

    t.start();
}
```

*You would of course, add exception handling and all that kind of good stuff.*

Note that, as opposed to directly creating a thread in your `threadStart` method, you could also use an Executor, or any other kind of thread pooling construct.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'll implement at latest. Unfortunately threads are not for free, so I'm still looking for a more listener like idea :)

Comment: @makciook - with this solution you create no additional threads but what you would have created already to run the tasks.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a referenece to the starting class in your runnable and 
call a changeState method on the parent class when the run method finishes

Comment: Also not. It's a whole lib, tons of classes I have only to run and know when they finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can benefit from Groovy `as` operator to coerce a closure into a `Runnable` object. Also, enums are cool for states:

```
class X implements Runnable {
    void run() {
        sleep 1000
        println "async task done"
    }
}

enum State { NOT_STARTED, DONE }

class Controller {
        State state = State.NOT_STARTED
        Thread t
        void threadStart() {
            t = Thread.start { new X().run(); changeState() } as Runnable
        }

        void changeState() { state = State.DONE }
}

controller = new Controller()
controller.threadStart()

assert controller.state == State.NOT_STARTED
controller.t.join()
assert controller.state == State.DONE
```

Comment: Looks nice, however e.g in grails controller it doesn't change my state for a defined object:
def newTask = new Task(state: 0)
Thread.start { x.run(); newTask.state = 2; newTask.save(); } as Runnable

Comment: In fact it doesn't ever get to the changeState() from your code. Fires x.run() and disappears...

Comment: I updated my code with the test i was using. The assertions works fine

Comment: Fixed it thanks. If you change state of an object from Domain, using obj.save() you have to invoke it as obj.withTransaction. Now it works